# Does Nintendo pass out HH Showcase houses in Canada?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I live in Canada and I've read somewhere that Nintendo passes out HH Showcase every Monday.
Is this only for the US or all of NA?

If it's only for the US, is there another way for me to get houses in my showcase without StreetPassing other players?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you live in Canada you should be able to go to the HH Showcase as Canada is a part of NA.

Comment: Yes, I CAN go to the showcase, but there are no houses. Does Nintendo give out houses via spotpass in Canada like in the US (from what Ive read on the internet)?